# Validation Summary and AJAX requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that allow us to easily "hijax" a standard HTML form, submitting it via AJAX rather than a standard POST.

One thing the plugin needs to handle is validation errors and in ASP.NET MVC's case, ModelState errors on the server.

I've written an Action Filter that intercepts AJAX requests and returns the Modelstate errors as JSON. This works fine for field errors (i.e. those that have an input on the form):

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    statusCode: {
        400: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            validator.showErrors(errors);
        }
    },
    success: function (response) {
        window.location.href = "/login/success";
    }
});
```

The jQuery Validate `showErrors` function looks for input elements with a `name` that matches the error key.

Since the standard convention in ASP.NET MVC is to do the following when you want to provide a "summary" error:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error without a key");
```

This causes jQuery validate to throw an exception.

The best solution I've come up with so far is to create a hidden input on my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="summary" disabled/> <!-- prevent it from being submitted -->
@Html.ValidationMessage("summary")
```

And then execute the following on the server when I want to display a "summary" error:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("summary", "Summary error");
```

This is not ideal since it doesn't work well with multiple errors. A nicer solution would be to hook into how the unobtrusive validation plugin handles summary errors but I can't see how to do that.